# Edit wordpress database table through the administration panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having some trouble, mostly from the lack of my knowledge on WordPress and I need some expert help. I am retrieving data from a table named *wp_words* in my WordPress database, and I am showing them in a table form, in a menu page in the WordPress administrator panel. I create a menu page called *Lexicon Testing* and the table is shown in that menu page. What I want to do is, when I click the edit button below each code (as shown in the picture), to be able to edit the rest of the lines fields on the same page. Like a quick edit function like in posts and pages. The way that I am retrieving data is shown n the code below. I would like some advice please and some guidance. Is it possible to do it like I want? Do I need to retrieve data another way to make it work like that? The way I used to retrieve data is on this page: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: Testing v1
  Description: Testing
  Version: 1.0
 */
if (!class_exists('WP_List_Table')) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class Lexicon_words_List extends WP_List_Table {

    /** Class constructor */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct([
            'singular' => __('Lexicon word', 'sp'), //singular name of the listed records
            'plural' => __('Lexicon words', 'sp'), //plural name of the listed records
            'ajax' => false //does this table support ajax?
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve customers data from the database
     *
     * @param int $per_page
     * @param int $page_number
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function get_lexicon_words($per_page = 5, $page_number = 1) {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}lexicon_words";
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['orderby'])) {
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . esc_sql($_REQUEST['orderby']);
            $sql .= !empty($_REQUEST['order']) ? ' ' . esc_sql($_REQUEST['order']) : ' ASC';
        }
        $sql .= " LIMIT $per_page";
        $sql .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, 'ARRAY_A');
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Delete a customer record.
     *
     * @param int $id customer ID
     */
    public static function delete_lexicon_word($id) {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->delete(
                "{$wpdb->prefix}lexicon_words", array('id' => $id)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Edit a customer record.
     *
     * @param int $id customer ID
     */
    public static function edit_lexicon_word($id) {

    }

    /**
     * Returns the count of records in the database.
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public static function record_count() {
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}lexicon_words";
        return $wpdb->get_var($sql);
    }

    /** Text displayed when no customer data is available */
    public function no_items() {
        _e('No words avaliable.', 'sp');
    }

    /**
     * Render a column when no column specific method exist.
     *
     * @param array $item
     * @param string $column_name
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function column_default($item, $column_name) {
        switch ($column_name) {
            case 'code':
            case 'text':
            case 'phrase':
            case 'context':
            case 'level':
            case 'lang':
                return $item[$column_name];
            default:
                return print_r($item, true); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
        }
    }

    /**
     * Render the bulk edit checkbox
     *
     * @param array $item
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function column_cb($item) {
        return sprintf(
                '<input type="checkbox" name="bulk-delete[]" value="%s" />', $item['id']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Method for code column
     *
     * @param array $item an array of DB data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function column_code($item) {
        $delete_nonce = wp_create_nonce('sp_delete_lexicon_word');
        $edit_nonce = wp_create_nonce('sp_edit_lexicon_word');
        $title = '<strong>' . $item['code'] . '</strong>';
        $actions = [
            'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&lexicon_word=%s&_wpnonce=%s">Edit</a>', esc_attr($_REQUEST['page']), 'edit', absint($item['id']), $edit_nonce),
            'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&lexicon_word=%s&_wpnonce=%s">Delete</a>', esc_attr($_REQUEST['page']), 'delete', absint($item['id']), $delete_nonce)
        ];
        return $title . $this->row_actions($actions);
    }

    /**
     *  Associative array of columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function get_columns() {
        $columns = [
            'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'code' => __('Code', 'sp'),
            'text' => __('Text', 'sp'),
            'phrase' => __('Phrase', 'sp'),
            'context' => __('Context', 'sp'),
            'level' => __('Level', 'sp'),
            'column_6' => __('Column 6', 'sp'),
            'column_7' => __('Column 7', 'sp'),
            'column_8' => __('Column 8', 'sp'),
            'column_9' => __('Column 9', 'sp'),
            'column_10' => __('Column 10', 'sp'),
            'column_11' => __('Column 11', 'sp'),
            'column_12' => __('Column 12', 'sp'),
            'column_13' => __('Column 13', 'sp'),
            'column_14' => __('Column 14', 'sp'),
            'column_15' => __('Column 15', 'sp'),
            'column_16' => __('Column 16', 'sp'),
            'lang' => __('Lang', 'sp')
        ];
        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * Columns to make sortable.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_sortable_columns() {
        $sortable_columns = array(
            'code' => array('code', true),
            'text' => array('text', false)
        );
        return $sortable_columns;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an associative array containing the bulk action
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_bulk_actions() {
        $actions = [
            'bulk-delete' => 'Delete'
        ];
        return $actions;
    }

    /**
     * Handles data query and filter, sorting, and pagination.
     */
    public function prepare_items() {
        $this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();
        /** Process bulk action */
        $this->process_bulk_action();
        $per_page = $this->get_items_per_page('lexicon_words_per_page', 5);
        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
        $total_items = self::record_count();
        $this->set_pagination_args([
            'total_items' => $total_items, //WE have to calculate the total number of items
            'per_page' => $per_page //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
        ]);
        $this->items = self::get_lexicon_words($per_page, $current_page);
    }

    public function process_bulk_action() {
        //Detect when a bulk action is being triggered...
        if ('delete' === $this->current_action()) {
            // In our file that handles the request, verify the nonce.
            $nonce = esc_attr($_REQUEST['_wpnonce']);
            if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'sp_delete_lexicon_word')) {
                die('Fatal Error');
            } else {
                self::delete_lexicon_word(absint($_GET['lexicon_word']));
                // esc_url_raw() is used to prevent converting ampersand in url to "#038;"
                // add_query_arg() return the current url
                //$origUrl = esc_attr($_REQUEST['page']);
                wp_redirect(esc_url_raw(add_query_arg(array('page' => 'lexicon_testing'), admin_url('admin.php'))));
                exit;
            }
        }
        if ('edit' === $this->current_action()) {
            // In our file that handles the request, verify the nonce.
            $nonce = esc_attr($_REQUEST['_wpnonce']);
            if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'sp_edit_lexicon_word')) {
                die('Fatal Error');
            } else {
                self::edit_lexicon_word(absint($_GET['lexicon_word']));
                // esc_url_raw() is used to prevent converting ampersand in url to "#038;"
                // add_query_arg() return the current url
                //$origUrl = esc_attr($_REQUEST['page']);
                wp_redirect(esc_url_raw(add_query_arg(array('page' => 'lexicon_testing'), admin_url('admin.php'))));
                exit;
            }
        }
        // If the delete bulk action is triggered
        if (( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'bulk-delete' ) || ( isset($_POST['action2']) && $_POST['action2'] == 'bulk-delete' )
        ) {
            $delete_ids = esc_sql($_POST['bulk-delete']);
            // loop over the array of record IDs and delete them
            foreach ($delete_ids as $id) {
                self::delete_lexicon_word($id);
            }
            // esc_url_raw() is used to prevent converting ampersand in url to "#038;"
            // add_query_arg() return the current url
            wp_redirect(esc_url_raw(add_query_arg(array('page' => 'lexicon_testing'), admin_url('admin.php'))));
            exit;
        }
    }

}

class SP_Plugin {

    // class instance
    static $instance;
    // customer WP_List_Table object
    public $lexicon_words_obj;

    // class constructor
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter('set-screen-option', [__CLASS__, 'set_screen'], 10, 3);
        add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'plugin_menu']);
    }

    public static function set_screen($status, $option, $value) {
        return $value;
    }

    public function plugin_menu() {
        $hook = add_menu_page(
                'Lexicon Testing', 'Lexicon Testing', 'manage_options', 'lexicon_testing', [$this, 'plugin_settings_page']
        );
        add_action("load-$hook", [$this, 'screen_option']);
    }

    /**
     * Plugin settings page
     */
    public function plugin_settings_page() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Lexicon Database Management</h2>

            <div id="poststuff">
                <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-2">
                    <div id="post-body-content">
                        <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
                            <form method="post">
                                <?php
                                $this->lexicon_words_obj->prepare_items();
                                $this->lexicon_words_obj->display();
                                ?>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Screen options
     */
    public function screen_option() {
        $option = 'per_page';
        $args = [
            'label' => 'Words',
            'default' => 5,
            'option' => 'lexicon_words_per_page'
        ];
        add_screen_option($option, $args);
        $this->lexicon_words_obj = new Lexicon_words_List();
    }

    /** Singleton instance */
    public static function get_instance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function edit_word_metabox() {
        add_meta_box('editword_metabox', '$title', 'editword_metabox_callback', 'lexicon_testing');
    }

    function editword_metabox_callback() {

    }

}

add_action('plugins_loaded', function () {
    SP_Plugin::get_instance();
});
```

[image]

Comment: you need Ajax support in your table, and it's not going to be few line to added here, so start looking around for something called wp_list_table ajax and you will find a lot of useful tutorial  and information

Comment: ok! thank you so much for the help and the suggestions. I was working blind before, now I have something to start